# Pre configuration before build, copying some files to directiory location using Automake

Tags: c++, gcc, configure, automake, autoreconf

I am building my project using Automake.  I have to copy few files before I start the build.  What should I do in configure.ac file to copy few files to some directory location before I start building?

Comment: Can't you just add the files to be copied as makefile dependencies?

Comment: Do you need to copy before building or before configuring?

Comment: I have to copy files before building